# Android Studios cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio-2.1

Ok guys, I know that this has already been posted countless times before, but I have tried everything in the other posts that are related to the android studios program saying that it cannot resolve the symbol 'R', not one thing has worked for me.

I have tried:

- cleaning my project
- Resynching my project
- reinstalling android studios
- creating a new project and copying and pasting all of my files in from my old project
- Rebuilding my project
- Checked my SDK Tools in the SDK Manager
- List item

I have spent quite some time on this project, my first android project, and now this happens. I do not know what to do, like I said, I have tried everything that the recent posts have said and nothing has worked for me. When the problem first started (earlier today), I was looking at the app gradle, I changed something, then reverted back to what it was before. After this, it asked me to sync my gradle with the project and all of a sudden, every time I used findViewByID(R.id.xxxxx), I get an error.

I just tried copying every file of code into a new project. After I finished, the code looked fine and there were no errors, however, after I closed and reopened Android Studios, I saw a bunch of extra java files called "R" and then they disappeared and the R symbol error popped up again. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I figured it out. The problem was in my xml, I had checked my xml before but it did not show any errors, however, when checking the console message from the gradle synch, it would show a few errors that the xml files did not mark as error. Thank you everyone who answered.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project? (Notice how it's important that you actually say what you've tried instead of just saying you've tried everything?)

Comment: rebuild and clean your project.

Comment: Also check for XML erros, those errors prevent R build.